# How to set up multiple tracks recording in Magix music maker

Tags: software, recording

How to set up multiple tracks recording at the same time in Magix music maker??

Comment: @Tetsujin Magix Music Maker is a very obscure application with not much documentation and resources available. There can be research without results, don't assume lack of research from lack of results only. Doing research doesn't guarantee finding answers.

Comment: @Tetsujin Can you post a link to the answer? Using both Google and the manual I can't find a concrete answer. I can find the question, but not a definitive answer. In fact, the first result links here!

Comment: @Tetsujin What? That user is not even sure about it. His quote: "Music maker record one track at a time.(if I am not wrong)". That being the only info available is more than enough to justify asking somewhere else. There is no definitive answer to be found. Also, multitrack recording is not exclusive to ASIO or "any substitute".

Comment: I've created a meta discussion regarding this question here: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/regarding-previous-research-efforts

Comment: Magix Music Maker cannot record to more than one (stereo) track at the same time.
A partly compatible software which can do this is Magix Music Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already know how to record one single track? You first click the rec button in the track box and then click record in the transport bar. This is the same for most (if not all) DAWs.

For multi-track recording you need to do the same, but in multiple tracks, before clicking record in the transport bar. Click the rec button of all the tracks you want to record to, then click record in the transport bar. This is also the same for most (if not all) DAWs.

What you might encounter is that when you arm one track for recording you disarm the previous one, in other words you can't activate recording in multiple tracks because activating it on one deactivates the previous. Some DAWs, like Ableton Live, do this.

In this case what you need to do is find the multiple-selection key. It is often the alt, control, or command key. You need to click the rec button of the tracks while holding that multiple-selection key.

There is no mention of multi-track recording in the manual, and google is not helping here, but it should be something the software is capable of.